# Is there a word or phrase which is to a question what a synonym is to a word?

Tags: synonyms, questions

I would like a title for a list of questions which are similar in wording but identical in meaning to the current question.

So if you are viewing the question:

> How many miles in a kilometre?

It would be the same question as:

> How many miles in 1000 metres?

I feel "Similar questions" would give the wrong meaning, especially as I would like to also list similar questions such as:

> How many yards in a mile?

Which is clearly a different question.

Comment: Why don't you think *similar* works for questions like "How many miles in a kilometer?" and "How many yards in a mile?"?

Comment: @Silenus It would work fine if not for my last point about having both synonym questions and similar.

Answer (score 8):

***[Synonymous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/synonymous)*** means

> equivalent in meaning.

The concept can be applied to words, phrases, declarative sentences, imperative sentences (that is, commands), and interrogative sentences (that is, questions).

***Synonymous questions*** are thus

> questions which are equivalent in meaning.

This phrase has some currency, as evinced by this [Google books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22synonymous%20questions%22).

Unfortunately, if you want a word for the relation between questions like "How many miles in a kilometre?" and "How many yards in a mile?", *synonymous* probably won't do. For that relation, ***similarity*** or ***analogy*** is probably your best bet. Such questions can be said to be ***similar questions*** or ***analogous questions***.

Comment: I'm wondering if a lower reading age word might be 'equivalent'?